# Question about the definition of involute of a plane curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, curves

I'm studying about involute of a plane curve from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hRY.png) and there's a small point that is really bothering me and I can not understand it.

Assuming curve is parameterized by arc length, the involute is defined as $$\gamma(t) = \beta(t) - t \beta'(t) $$

Why is there a negative sign? Like it says in the link I added, the bob's position is at distance $t$ in direction $-\beta'(t)$. I can't see how this negative sign has to be there for every curve in general. If the tangent line of $\beta$ at point $t$ is  $\beta(t) + \lambda \beta'(t)$, then starting from $\beta(t)$ I can move along the line is either direction depending on $\lambda$. Why must it be negative in the case of the involute?

Comment: $s = t$ in your linked page.  Why not here as  well?  Cheers!

Comment: Edited it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model for the involute is this: Take a circle, with scotch tape wrapped around it. Start to peel the scotch tape off and follow the point $P$ at the end of the tape. As you go counterclockwise around the circle, the tape is tangent, but the line segment from the point of contact to $P$ goes in the direction opposite to the (counterclockwise) tangent vector to the circle.

Comment: Thank you! so if I understood correctly, the tangent vector is pointing in the direction of increasing $t$, but in order to actually draw the involute, we start from from point of contact going to $P$ in the opposide direction

Comment: Right. You want to think of unwrapping a string from the curve :)

Comment: +1 For explaining the model with scotch tape.